# How to Improve Code Code Coverage for below Apex Controller?

Tags: apex, community

> Below is the Apex Controller and Test Class which i have written for it.

```
public with sharing class Condosearchcontroller { 


public list <Condo__c> Cond {get;set;}
public String LeadRecordId {get;set;}
public string beds {get;set;} 
public string squarefootage {get;set;}
public String SFminimum {get;set;}
public String SFmaximum {get;set;}
public string InitialListPrice {get;set;}
public String ILPminimum {get;set;}
public String ILPmaximum {get;set;}
public string Unitnamevf {get;set;}
public Boolean refreshPage {get; set;}

public Condosearchcontroller() {

} 
public Condosearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

   }  

public List<SelectOption> getbedsOptions() {
      List<SelectOption> bedsoptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    bedsoptions.add(new SelectOption('','ALL'));
    bedsoptions.add(new SelectOption('0','0'));
    bedsoptions.add(new SelectOption('1','1'));
    bedsoptions.add(new SelectOption('2','2'));
    bedsoptions.add(new SelectOption('3','3'));

    return bedsoptions;
}


  public PageReference  Search(){


    String SFmin = SFminimum.remove(',');
    String SFmax = SFmaximum.remove(','); 
    String ILPmin = ILPminimum.remove(',');
    String ILPmax = ILPmaximum.remove(',');

    string searchquery= 'select name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c,Status__c from Condo__c where name!=null and Status__c in (\'Available\',\'Unsold\') ';


           if (beds == 'ALL'){
               searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = 0,1,2,3 ';
              }
              else 
            if (beds >= '0'){
               searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+'';
               }
               else

            if (SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum >'0') {
               searchquery+= ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFmin+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmax+' ';
               }
               else
            if (ILPminimum > '0' && ILPmaximum >'0') {
               searchquery += 'and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPmin+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmax+' ';
                 }


            if (beds >= '0' && SFminimum >'0' && SFmaximum > '0'){
               searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFmin+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmax+' '; 
               }
                else
             if (beds >= '0' && ILPminimum > '0' && ILPmaximum >'0'){

                 searchquery += 'and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPmin+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmax+' ';
                 }

              if(beds >= '0' && SFminimum >'0' && SFmaximum >'0' && ILPminimum >'0' && ILPmaximum >'0'){

                 searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFmin+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmax+' and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPmin+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmax+' ';
                  }
                  else
             if(beds >= '0' && SFminimum >'0') {

                  searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c  >= '+SFmin+' ';
                 }
                  else
              if(beds >= '0' && SFmaximum > '0') {

                  searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c  <= '+SFmax+' ';
                  }
                  else
              if(beds >= '0' && ILPminimum > '0') {

                 searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c  >= '+ILPmin+' ';
                 }
                 else
               if(beds >= '0' && ILPmaximum > '0') {

                 searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c  <= '+ILPmax+' ';
                 }
                 else
               if(SFminimum > '0') {

                  searchquery += ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFmin+' ';
                 }
                 else
                 if(SFmaximum >'0') {

                  searchquery += ' and Square_Footage__c  <= '+SFmax+' ';
                  }
                  else
                 if(ILPminimum > '0')
                 {
                   searchquery += ' and Initial_List_Price__c  >= '+ILPmin+'';
                 }
                 else
                 if(ILPmaximum > '0') {

                 searchquery += ' and Initial_List_Price__c  <= '+ILPmax+' ';
               }

               if ( SFmin != null && SFmin.isAlpha() ||  SFmax != null && SFmax.isAlpha() ||  ILPmin != null && ILPmin.isAlpha() ||   ILpmax != null && ILPmax.isAlpha()){
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter Numerical values for SquareFootage and Price Fields'));
        }
          else    
       cond = Database.query(searchquery);
       return null;
}

Public Pagereference addtolead() {
Id UnitId;
 Unitnamevf=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('UnitNameParam');
  LeadRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

    List<Lead> Lds = new List<Lead>([select Id,Unit__c from Lead where Id=                     :LeadRecordId]);
       List<Condo__c> Cnd = New List<Condo__c>([select Id,Name from Condo__c       where Name= :Unitnamevf]);
        if(!Cnd.isEmpty()){
       UnitId = Cnd[0].Id; 
     Lds[0].Unit__c = UnitId; 
      update Lds[0];
        }

 refreshPage=true;  
return null;
   }

    public void Reset(){ 

beds = null;
SFminimum = null;
SFmaximum = null;
ILPminimum = null;
ILPmaximum = null;
if(Cond != null) {
Cond.clear();
}
```

}

}

> when i run the below test class

```
@isTest
  Public Class TestCondosearchcontroller {

   static  Testmethod void Bedstestmethod(){
  String SFmin;
String SFmax;
   String ILPmin;
   String ILPmax;

//create a CIM Asset
    CIM_Assets__c myAsset = new           CIM_Assets__c(Name='condolistname1',Property_Type__c='Condo');
    insert myAsset;

    //create some condo's and add to the asset
    Condo__c Cnd1 = new            Condo__c(CIM_Assets__c=myAsset.Id,Beds__c=1,Initial_List_Price__c=1200000,Status__c='UnSold',Square_Footage__c = 1000);
    Condo__c Cnd2 = new Condo__c(CIM_Assets__c=myAsset.Id,Beds__c=0,Initial_List_Price__c=1500000,Status__c='Available',Square_Footage__c = 1200);

    Condo__c Cnd3 = new Condo__c(CIM_Assets__c=myAsset.Id,Beds__c=2,Initial_List_Price__c=1300000,Status__c='UnSold',Square_Footage__c = 1300);
    Condo__c Cnd4 = new Condo__c(CIM_Assets__c=myAsset.Id,Beds__c=3,Initial_List_Price__c=1400000,Status__c='Sold',Square_Footage__c = 1400);

    Condo__c Cnd5 = new Condo__c(CIM_Assets__c=myAsset.Id,Beds__c=1,Initial_List_Price__c=1345000,Status__c='Sold',Square_Footage__c = 850);
    Condo__c Cnd6 = new Condo__c(CIM_Assets__c=myAsset.Id,Beds__c=1,Initial_List_Price__c=1450000,Status__c='Available',Square_Footage__c = 1350);

    Condo__c[] allCondos = new Condo__c[]{Cnd1,Cnd2,Cnd3,Cnd4,Cnd5,Cnd6};
    insert allCondos;

PageReference pageRef = Page.CondosSearchPage;
pageRef.getParameters().put('beds', 'ALL');
pageRef.getParameters().put('SFmin', '500');
pageRef.getParameters().put('SFmax', '1500');
pageRef.getParameters().put('ILPmin', '1,000,000');
pageRef.getParameters().put('ILPmax', '1,500,000');
Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);


Condosearchcontroller cndser =new Condosearchcontroller();
cndser.Search();

   }

  static Testmethod void getBedsOptions(){

    Test.StartTest();
     Condosearchcontroller cndser = new Condosearchcontroller();
     cndser.getbedsOptions();
    Test.StopTest();

}
     static Testmethod void AddtoLead(){

  string Unitnamevf = 'R2-202';
  Id UnitId; 
   Boolean Refreshpage;

  CIM_Assets__c CIM = New CIM_Assets__c();
 CIM.name = 'Test CIM';
 CIM.Property_Type__c = 'Condo';
 insert CIM; 

    Condo__c Cnd2 = New Condo__c();
    //Cnd2.name = 'R1-10111';
    Cnd2.CIM_Assets__c = CIM.Id; 
      insert Cnd2;

     Lead ld = New Lead();
     ld.LastName = 'Test Lead';
    ld.Company = 'Test Company';
    insert ld;

       Test.StartTest();
     if(Cnd2 != null){
     UnitId = Cnd2.Id;
      ld.Unit__c = UnitId;
       Update ld;
      }
        Condosearchcontroller cndser = new Condosearchcontroller();
  cndser.addtolead();
  Test.StopTest();
     }


static Testmethod void Reset(){

String beds = '3';
String SFmin = '500';
String SFmax = '1000';
String ILPmin = '1,000,000';
String ILPmax = '1,500,000';

test.starttest();
Condosearchcontroller cndser = new Condosearchcontroller();
  cndser.Reset();
  Test.StopTest();

   }
  }
```

> I am constantly getting a error message saying
>   TestCondosearchcontroller
>   Bedstestmethod : Fail
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Class.Condosearchcontroller.Search: line 40, column 1
>   Class.TestCondosearchcontroller.Bedstestmethod:  line 59, column 1​

Comment: In addition to the answer below, be aware that your tests are not actually testing anything. All they are doing is executing lines of code. You are not testing for appropriate outcomes after the code is executed. This leave your code vulnerable to failure while your "test" continue to pass. Proper test methods will query for and assert data after tests have ran. Also breaking the test methods up into functional pieces will help. A test method does not have to cover everything in a few methods rather many methods each testing a specific functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You have a series of lines in your constructor like

```
String SFmin = SFminimum.remove(',');
```

When you instantiated the controller without specifying values for these variables, then they are left null.

You cannot call .remove() on a null variable.

One way to guard against a null value would be to use the ternary operator

```
String SFmin = (SFminimum == null) ? 'SomeSensibleDefault' : SFminimum.remove(',');
```

This means, if SFminimum is null then use the value 'SomeSensibleDefault' otherwise use the result of SFminimum.remove(',')

Answer (score 2):

Doug B is correct that you should guard against nulls. Eric is also right that your test isn't testing anything.

In addition to those, it doesn't appear that you are actually pulling the values you put in to the query string in to your controller variables. You should have a line like:

```
String beds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('beds');
```

Without that, your variables will always be null.